# Further optimization of finding max in a stack

Tags: c++, stack

My problem is to insert an element, pop the last inserted element and printed the max in the given. I am using 2 stacks for the purpose and it is optimized based on most suggested techniques available. But I still need further optimization for the case where number of queries, q <=100000 and test cases<=100. The following is my code as of now:

```
int main() {
int t,q;
cin>>t;
char query;
int detail;
for(int test=0;test<t;test++)
{
    cout<<"Case "<<test+1<<":\n";
    cin>>q;
    stack<int> s;
    stack<int> max;
    for(int i=0;i<q;i++)
    {
        cin>>query;
        if(query=='A')
        {
            cin>>detail;                    
            s.push(detail);
            if(max.empty())
                max.push(detail);
            else if(detail>=max.top())
                max.push(detail);
        }
        else if(query=='R')
        {
            if(!s.empty())
            {
                if(s.top()==max.top())
                    max.pop();
                s.pop();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(max.empty())
                cout<<"Empty\n";
            else
                cout<<max.top()<<"\n";
        }
    }

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Consider using not two `stack`s, but `stack<pair<int, int>>`. In this case it will probably result in better cache locality

Comment: @Jarod42 I don't understand. Are you inserting those elements? What operations are you performing? And why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: With following input of `4 A 1 A 1 R Q`, you will print `"Empty"` whereas there is still `1` in `s`. and bad thing happen if we added a following `R`. [Demo](https://ideone.com/2BrQUt)

Comment: I'm assuming that your input is actually A6 A1 R Q, thus inserting 6 first, 1 then, remove the recent element (1) and display the max. When 6 is inserted, it is inserted into both s and max stack. 1 is inserted only into s. When removed, 1 is removed only from s (still retaining 6 in max stack) So printing max will give 6.

Comment: My input is not your working case `A6 A1 R Q` but `A1 A1 R Q` which prints `Empty` (`if(detail>max.top())` should probably be `if(detail>=max.top())`).

Comment: Great catch! But the TLE is still not solved. I'm giving some more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what do you mean by 'optimize' (minimize memory usage in your cases, improve execution time or just referring to algorithm efficiency). Following comment from @alexeykuzmin0 , the code would look as follows:

```
std::stack<std::pair<int, int>> stack;

for (int i = 0; i<q; i++)
{
  std::cin >> query;
  if (query == 'A')
  {
    std::cin >> detail;
    int max = stack.empty() ? detail : std::max(detail, stack.top().second);
    stack.push(std::make_pair(detail, max));
  }
  else if (query == 'R')
  {
    if (!stack.empty())
    {
       stack.pop();
    }
  }
  else
  {
    if (stack.empty())
      std::cout << "Empty\n";
    else
      std::cout << stack.top().second << "\n";
  }
}
```

Additionally it looks like you're not using the history of inserted items for anything, thus we can remove the pair and solve it using single stack.

```
std::stack<int> stack;

for (int i = 0; i<q; i++)
{
  std::cin >> query;
  if (query == 'A')
  {
    std::cin >> detail;
    int max = stack.empty() ? detail : std::max(detail, stack.top());
    stack.push(max);
  }
  else if (query == 'R')
  {
    if (!stack.empty())
    {
      stack.pop();
    }
  }
  else
  {
    if (stack.empty())
      std::cout << "Empty\n";
    else
      std::cout << stack.top() << "\n";
  }
}
```

Also remember to measure performance (timings) in release mode builds, with optimizations on. (don't measure performance on debug builds)

Comment: Well, you don't seem to check any value so I assume 'R' will just remove the most recently added item ? thus the stack in case of your A6 A1 R Q will be  6 -> 6, 6 -> 6 ? Unless I misunderstood concept of 'R' query. Could you provide input for which this is not valid?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your solution.

The problem still persists. I'm thinking that optimizing on my read/write will help.

Comment: but what is 'the problem' you are referring to?

Comment: Resolved. I was getting more runtime because I was using cin/cout. Using scanf/printf resolved it. Nevertheless, your solution is the optimized version possible in terms of the algorithm space/time. Thanks!

Comment: std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false); [source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio) might help.